# add character to my field in form periodic in a loop

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, loops

i need a php code that user click on send button in my form automatically add a  different character like a - b - c -d to field input.
for example this is my form html code.

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">

  <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone">
 <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

and in action.php like this

```
  echo $_POST['phone'];
```

user enter 002255 in phone number field and click send button
print 002255 now .

but i want when user click send button for first time , print a002255
and when click send button for second time , print b002255
and next c002255 and next d002255
then make a loop and when click for fifth time , print a002255 again.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: nothing unfortunately.

Comment: Well this is not a free code writing service, show us your attempt and we will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

What will happened after reaching letter Z? In example below it will reset. I think you need to create an array and index to it. So when user click button index goes +1. Index will be on session because it has to store number. Am beginner too and trying to figure it out. Example:

```
session_start();
$alphabet = array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z');

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    if($_SESSION["Number"] == 0) {
        print_r($alphabet[0] . "002255");
        $_SESSION["Number"] += 1;
    } else {
        print_r($alphabet[$_SESSION["Number"]] . "002255");
        $_SESSION["Number"] += 1;

        if($_SESSION["Number"] > 26) {
            $_SESSION["Number"] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i need just a,b,c,d .it is not necessary code continue to z. when user reaching letter d again add character a. like a loop.

Comment: @lernoweb delete other letters from array in example. Am sure my code can be simplimized.